# jquery throws Object has no method 'replace' on .animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Using jquery 1.7.1

this is the simple function I'm trying to run:

```
$('#large-boxes').dblclick(function(e){
  var element = $(e.target);

  boxes.disappear(element);
});

boxes = {
    disappear: function(element){
    console.log(element);
    element.animate({
        height: 0,
        width: 0,
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    }, 100);
},
}
```

which outputs this in the console when run:

```
boxes.js:60

[
 <div id=​"4" class=​"ui-draggable">​</div>​
]

jquery.min.js:4

Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
  var i;
  var newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
  for (i in this) {
    if (i == 'clone') continue;
    if (this[i] && typeof this[i] == "object") {
      newObj[i] = this[i].clone();
    } else newObj[i] = this[i]
  } return newObj;
} has no method 'replace'
```

At first I thought the brackets around the element object might indicate an array, but it seems like that's just the notation on a jquery object.

The element animates properly, and if I remove the .animate function and just set all the values with .css, I get no error.

Any ideas?

Comment: the more I read your question, the more I'm confused...so it animates properly; if you set the values with `css()` it works.  So when does it throw the error? on the `console.log`?

Comment: On further investigation, I've found that setting css properties with  `element.css('background', 'red');` works without an error, but `element.css({'background': 'red'});` throws the same uncaught TypeError

Answer (score 1):

you might have to add `$(element)`.  Hard to tell how you are actually calling this function, though.

Answer (score 1):

Let me do a wild guess.
That:

```
Object function () {
   var i;
   var newObj = (this instanceof Array) ? [] : {};
   ......
```

might be your own function, that has spoiled namespace of Object. IOW somewhere in your
sourcecode you're doing eg:

```
Object.prototype.myclone = function() { ... }
```

Now $.fn.animate( prop, ... ) will pick that up, in a for cycle

```
for( p in prop ) { ....
```

because prop is just regular Object:

```
{   height: 0,  width: 0,   top: 0,   left: 0  }
```

And from that on, your 'myclone' has it's own life and the failure you see might be long after that.
The best answer I can give you, is to 'grep newObj .*' your sourcefiles and all your libraries.
Just let us know if this is shooting on the target...